# Show/hide bones or slots in Spine animation

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Spine runtime with cocos2d in my iPad application. In my animation, some slots/bones are hidden initially. When the animation runs, I want to show/hide those slots/bones on touch. I am using the below code to run the animation.

```
CCSkeletonAnimation *animationNode = [CCSkeletonAnimation skeletonWithFile:@"Skeleton.json" atlasFile:@"Skeleton.atlas" scale:0];

[animationNode setDelegate:self];
[animationNode setSkin:@"Head"];


[animationNode setToSetupPose];
[animationNode setSlotsToSetupPose];
```

How can I hide/show other bones/slots?

Comment: Hi, I found the issue after many research myself. Slot can be hide with as below:
Slot *test = [animationNode findSlot:@"SLOTNAME"];
Slot_setAttachment(test,0);

And can be show by this:
Slot *test2 = [animationNode findSlot:@"SLOTNAME"];
spSlotData *p1 = test1->data;
Slot_create(p1,test2->skeleton,test2->bone);
Slot_setToSetupPose(test2);